# C/C++ - How can I convert Buffer.BlockCopy (C#) to C/C++

Tags: c#, c++, c

I have the following function in `C#`:

```
public Matrix<float> ConcatDescriptors(IList<Matrix<float>> descriptors)
{
    int cols = descriptors[0].Cols;
    int rows = descriptors.Sum(a => a.Rows);

    float[,] concatedDescs = new float[rows, cols];

    int offset = 0;

    foreach (var descriptor in descriptors)
    {
        // append new descriptors
        Buffer.BlockCopy(descriptor.ManagedArray, 0, concatedDescs, offset, sizeof(float) * descriptor.ManagedArray.Length);
        offset += sizeof(float) * descriptor.ManagedArray.Length;
    }

    return new Matrix<float>(concatedDescs);
}
```

And I am trying to translate it to `C` or `C++`. I think it is fairly straightforward, however, I am stuck on the line:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(descriptor.ManagedArray, 0, concatedDescs, offset, sizeof(float) * descriptor.ManagedArray.Length);
```

How can I recreate this same line of code in `C` or `C++`?

Answer (score 4):

In C, the equivalent would be `memcpy`.

In C++ you can still use `memcpy`, and there's also `std::copy`.

Note that C and C++ allow pointers (or iterators) into the middle of an array, so while C# passes a handle to the entire array and a beginning index, in C and C++ you are expected to do the pointer arithmetic to find the beginning before calling the function.

Also be careful about number of bytes vs number of objects.  `Buffer.BlockCopy` measures both the starting index and number of items in bytes.  `memcpy` measures number of items in bytes also.  `std::copy` measures in elements.  And C and C++ pointer arithmetic operate on number of elements.  If you cast your pointer to `char*` first then elements and bytes become the same.  (C and C++ `char` is exactly one byte, unlike C# `char` which is more like C++ `wchar_t`)